# Facebook login cancelled on v4.6.0 when calling from a fragment

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-fragments

I have created an Android app. I have implemented Facebook login.

I have an activity with a fragment. The fragment has one Facebook login button. I am following the http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-add-facebook-login-to-your-android-app--cms-23837.

I have added the followings in activity.

1.**Initialization** of facebooksdk

2.**CallbackManager** creation.

3.in **onActivityResult** getting the CallbackManager getActivityResult.

4.in **onResume** activateApp

5.in **onPause** deactivateApp

I have added the registerCallback in fragment. But it is always shows login attempt cancelled as it is calling onCancel() method.

```
  facebookLoginButton.registerCallback(MainActivity.callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Login attempt canceled.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Login attempt failed.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

It is working if I implement in another activity.

Comment: Please post some code or stacktrace here.

Comment: I think I have seen this before but I cannot recall exactly. Have you requested permissions like Read and Publish? If you need any?

Comment: LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", " user_birthday", "user_friends"));


I have added this in Activity

Comment: FYI, sometimes you might want to specify LoginBehavior - because if you have Facebook app installed, it will attempt to login with FB and sometimes that is not what you want either

Comment: I had uninstalled the facebook app before testing.